# Optimal Rotation Before Curve Fitting

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, polynomial

I am fitting a 1-dimensional polynomial to a set of data points $\{(x_1,y_1,z_1),...,(x_N,y_N,z_N)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ using least squares regression.

My first instinct was to choose $x$ as an explanatory variable and perform regression on the sets $\{(x_1,y_1),...(x_N,y_N)\}$ and $\{(x_1,z_1),...,(x_N,z_N)$ separately. This would yield two functions $f_y, f_z$.  My curve would then be given by $\{(x,f_y(x),f_z(x)) : x \in [a, b]\}$.  Where $a,b$ are appropriately chosen.

However, I don't think this is optimal as the x-coordinates may be identical in a worst-case scenario.  My instinct is that I should perform PCA on the data-set beforehand and use the principal axis as my explanatory variable.  Is this optimal in some sense or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: How are these data values measured? What is the basis for assuming they can be described or approximated by a polynomial function? How do you plan to account for variation between the data and your fit? This information is important for guiding the selection of a fitting procedure.

Comment: Assume for the sake of argument that my data is normally distributed around a 1-dimensional polynomial curve in R^3.  (My question is more academic than anything.)  I am wondering if there is an optimal choice of an "axis" to use as my explanatory variable.

Comment: Some clarification of the meaning of "polynomial curve" might help, because there are several standard ones. Would it be (a) the image of a function $t\to(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ whose components are all polynomial functions or (b) the zero set of a collection of polynomials in the variables $(x,y,z)$? Note that in either case, rotations will usually be of little use: as linear transformations they would merely replace one polynomial with another of the same degree. (You cannot generally hope that any rotation will make $x(t)=t$.)

Comment: I meant (a).  I should clarify- I am not attempting to make the data look linear through a rotation.  I am asking how to choose my "t" to do polynomial regression with if all I'm given is un-ordered set of measurements from $\mathbb{R}^3$.  One idea I had was to find the PCA axis of the set, then use the projected value of each member of the set onto the axis as the "t" to use for regression.

Comment: My point is that you cannot find any such parameter in general. Given that negative outlook, we ought to turn towards understanding what you are really trying to accomplish with your data and focus on that, rather than going down what looks like a fruitless path.